# VirtualBox crashing with Windows 8 guest & Guest Additions

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-8

I'm trying to install the Guest Additions for Windows 8 x64 running in VirtualBox 4.2.4 OSE on a Linux x64 host.  The Guest Additions installer will, every time, crash the entire VM, bringing it totally to a halt, when it attempts to install the display driver.  (Go figure.)  By rebooting into safe mode, I managed to get the installation to complete, but when I reboot in regular mode, the guest won't even finish booting (presumable due to the borked display driver).  Does anyone know how to fix this or if there is a workaround?  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a VirtualBox bug.  I can't reproduce it any more.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into the VM's Display settings and disable 3D and 2D acceleration.
2. Set Display memory to 128M.
3. Run the VM, login to Windows.
4. Load IE, get the Guest Additions ISO from Oracle's FTP site [http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/]. (Incidentally, IE on Metro is pretty slick. It's not the same IE as in the screen shot.)
5. Double-click the saved ISO. Win8 can read and execute ISOs.
6. Run the installer.
7. The screen might go black and stay black for a while. Just be patient.
8. After the installer finishes, shutdown Windows.
9. Go into the VM's Display settings, and enable 3D and 2D acceleration.
10. Restart the VM. If the video is funky, go back and disable 3D.

Source: [Rich Levin](https://plus.google.com/103929740436666277619/posts/R3TjJ65vi9u)

Comment: Hmmm.  3D acceleration makes the VM crash entirely; it's not just "funky."  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Even with Guest Addition installed?

Comment: Yes, with Guest Additions.  To clarify:  without Guest Additions, everything works swimmingly (except without Guest Additions, obviously :), but *with* Guest Additions, Windows won't boot all the way up if 3D accel. is enabled.  With 3D disabled, it will boot.